# Use same page template for parent and child pages in a theme

Tags: templates, page-template, child-pages

I am working on a template which one uses on both parent and child pages.

Suppose I have a:

**`template name: TEST`**

I need to use that template on both parent and child pages:

**`Parent page name -> test1 -> template name:TEST`**

**`Child page name -> test2 -> Parent page test1 -> template name: TEST`**

Comment: Automatically? Just setting the template on the child page isn't enough?

Comment: A child theme already uses the templates that a parent offers?  So from the page you should be able to choose the template whichever theme you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `save_post` action to do it.

I think its better than the other option to check everytime the page load because it won't effects your clients and will not run everytime the page load.

Also you need to check if its the post parent its the one that saved so you will update his childrens.

Check this:

```
function set_child_page_template( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
    // Check for post type page
    if( $post->post_type === 'page' ) {
        // Check if its a child page
        if( $post->post_parent !== 0 ) {
            // If its child get the post parent template
            $parent_template = get_post_meta( $post->post_parent, '_wp_page_template', true );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_wp_page_template', $parent_template );
        } else {
            // If its parent update all his childs
            $parent_template = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_wp_page_template', true );
            $children = get_pages( ['child_of'=>$post_id] );
            foreach( $children as $child ) {
                update_post_meta( $child->ID, '_wp_page_template', $parent_template );
            }
        }
    }

}
add_action('save_post', 'set_child_page_template', 10, 3);
```